# DynamoDB - How does GSI creation time work for On-Demand tables?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Normally AWS recommend increasing write capacity to the table to facilitate the GSI creation, however since I'm working with an On-Demand pricing table I'm not sure if that advice is still applicable. will it automatically use as much write capacity as it can, or should I switch back to provisioned capacity to do the GSI creation and set the WCUs to a high amount?

I tried leaving it in on-demand pricing and it took a little over an hour to add a GSI to a table with 15 million records, I would like to perform the same action on a table with 12 billion records in it but I'm worried that it may take weeks to add a single GSI.

Comment: I asked AWS support this question and apparently it can take a very long time for the index to fully update, so my estimate of weeks was indeed accurate. Ended up migrating the data to a new table instead.